# iOS: Select a GIF from the photo library, convert to NSData for use in multipart/form-data

Tags: iphone, nsdata, gif

What's currently working in my code:

I select a JPG or PNG from the Photo Library (using standard ImagePicker methods), and convert that image to NSData using:

```
self.myImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImage, 0.9);
```

which I then post to a server using multipart/form-data.

I now want to do the same for a GIF, while retaining the original GIF data (so that an animated GIF going into the library, comes back out still animating).

In didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo, I am able to get the URL of the original GIF using

```
self.myGIFURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL].
```

Here's one example of what that might get me:

> assets-library://asset/asset.GIF?id=1000000034&ext=GIF

Here are two ways I've tried now to push this GIF into NSData, and each time I myImageData shows (null).

I've tried to use initWithContentsOfURL:

```
NSData *dataFromGIFURL = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: myGIFURL];
self.myImageData = dataFromGIFURL;
[dataFromGIFURL release];
```

Then I tried converting the NSURL to a string for initWithContentsOfFile:

```
NSString *stringFromURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", myGIFURL];
NSData *dataFromGIFURL = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: stringFromURL];
self.myImageData = dataFromGIFURL;
[dataFromGIFURL release];
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL key doesn't appear until iOS 4.1. I therefore take it as implicit in your question that it's fine to use the AssetsLibrary framework, which appeared in iOS only at 4.0. In which case, you can use the following:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
        didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [library assetForURL:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL]
        resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset)
        {
            ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [asset defaultRepresentation];
            
            NSLog(@"size of asset in bytes: %d", [representation size]);
            
            unsigned char bytes[4];
            [representation getBytes:bytes fromOffset:0 length:4 error:nil];
            NSLog(@"first four bytes: %02x (%c) %02x (%c) %02x (%c) %02x (%c)",
                               bytes[0], bytes[0], 
                               bytes[1], bytes[1], 
                               bytes[2], bytes[2], 
                               bytes[3], bytes[3]);

            [library autorelease];
        }
        failureBlock:^(NSError *error)
        {
            NSLog(@"couldn't get asset: %@", error);

            [library autorelease];
        }
    ];
}
```

So, you create an ALAssetsLibrary, ask it to find you the asset with the URL specified (it understands the assets-library:// URL scheme), then when you get the asset you grab its default representation and use that to feed you the bytes. They'll be the actual on-disk bytes, the default representation for an asset from the library being its on-disk form.

For example, selecting a particular GIF I grabbed at random from Google images, from an image picker wired up to a delegate with that method in it gives me the output:

> 2011-03-03 23:17:37.451
> IPTest[1199:307] size of asset in
> bytes: 174960
>
> 2011-03-03 23:17:37.459
> IPTest[1199:307] first four bytes: 47
> (G) 49 (I) 46 (F) 38 (8)

So that's the beginning of the standard GIF header. Picking PNGs or JPGs gives the recognisable first four bytes of the PNG and JPG headers.

EDIT: to finish the thought, obviously you can use ALAssetRepresentation to read all of the bytes describing the file into a suitably malloc'd C array, then use NSData +(id)dataWithBytes:length: (or, more likely, +dataWithBytesNoCopy:length:freeWhenDone:) to wrap that into an NSData.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the thorough response. Let me dig into it and see how it works for me.

Comment: It worked! The part after “obviously you can...” took me a little while. (I’m new to to this.)

Comment: Oh, sorry! I just realised I'd dealt with getting the bytes but forgotten to answer the NSData part of the question and came back to tack something on. I should have taken more care. I'd malloc a block of the size given by the asset representation, get the asset representation to write into that then wrap it in an NSData, handing over ownership of the memory (via freeWhenDone:). You could also create an NSMutableData with the correct storage then get the asset representation to write to its mutableBytes property. But I'm sure you've figured these things out now...

Comment: Interesting. On iPhone 5s 8.2 I keep getting  first four bytes: ff (ÿ) d8 (Ø) ff (ÿ) e0 (à) , while it works fine on 5s simulator.

Comment: this is deprecated

Answer (score 6):

Here's a version that uses the newer Photos framework:

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    NSURL * refUrl = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
    if (refUrl) {
        PHAsset * asset = [[PHAsset fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:@[refUrl] options:nil] lastObject];
        if (asset) {
            PHImageRequestOptions *options = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
            options.synchronous = YES;
            options.networkAccessAllowed = NO;
            options.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeHighQualityFormat;
            [[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageDataForAsset:asset options:options resultHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable imageData, NSString * _Nullable dataUTI, UIImageOrientation orientation, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {
                NSNumber * isError = [info objectForKey:PHImageErrorKey];
                NSNumber * isCloud = [info objectForKey:PHImageResultIsInCloudKey];
                if ([isError boolValue] || [isCloud boolValue] || ! imageData) {
                    // fail
                } else {
                    // success, data is in imageData
                }
            }];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL is deprecated

Comment: and how to retrieve the NSdata if it's In the cloud ?

Comment: Apple does have a tendency to keep things fresh. Lucky for you, XCode has a super useful feature. If you click on a deprecation warning in the IDE, it actually TELLS YOU how to fix the problem.  In this case, "UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL' was deprecated in iOS 11.0: Replace with public API: UIImagePickerControllerPHAsset".

Answer (score 4):

Here's Eli's version using Swift 3:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String: Any]) {
    guard let imageURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? URL else { return }
    guard let asset = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [imageURL], options: nil).lastObject else { return }

    if picker.sourceType == .photoLibrary || picker.sourceType == .savedPhotosAlbum {
        let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
        options.isSynchronous = true
        options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = false
        options.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
        PHImageManager.default().requestImageData(for: asset, options: options) { data, uti, orientation, info in
            guard let info = info else { return }

            if let error = info[PHImageErrorKey] as? Error {
                log.error("Cannot fetch data for GIF image: \(error)")
                return
            }

            if let isInCould = info[PHImageResultIsInCloudKey] as? Bool, isInCould {
                log.error("Cannot fetch data from cloud. Option for network access not set.")
                return
            }

            // do something with data (it is a Data object)
        }
    } else {
        // do something with media taken via camera
    }
}
```