# How can i upload an image to server directory directly form iOS using FTP

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ftp, objective-c++

I've searching a lot on how to upload images from my camera roll to a server directory and i didn't found anything!So i've downloaded the sample code from Apple(SimpleFTPSample),and i took these code bellow:

```
- (void)_startSend:(NSString *)filePath
{
    BOOL                    success;
    NSURL *                 url;
    CFWriteStreamRef        ftpStream;

    assert(filePath != nil);
    assert([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]);
    assert( [filePath.pathExtension isEqual:@"png"] || [filePath.pathExtension isEqual:@"jpg"] );

    assert(self.networkStream == nil);      // don't tap send twice in a row!
    assert(self.fileStream == nil);         // ditto

    // First get and check the URL.

    url = [[AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate] smartURLForString:self.urlText.text];
    success = (url != nil);

    if (success) {
        // Add the last part of the file name to the end of the URL to form the final 
        // URL that we're going to put to.

        url = [NSMakeCollectable(
            CFURLCreateCopyAppendingPathComponent(NULL, (CFURLRef) url, (CFStringRef) [filePath lastPathComponent], false)
        ) autorelease];
        success = (url != nil);
    }

    // If the URL is bogus, let the user know.  Otherwise kick off the connection.

    if ( ! success) {
        self.statusLabel.text = @"Invalid URL";
    } else {

        // Open a stream for the file we're going to send.  We do not open this stream; 
        // NSURLConnection will do it for us.

        self.fileStream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithFileAtPath:filePath];
        assert(self.fileStream != nil);

        [self.fileStream open];

        // Open a CFFTPStream for the URL.

        ftpStream = CFWriteStreamCreateWithFTPURL(NULL, (CFURLRef) url);
        assert(ftpStream != NULL);

        self.networkStream = (NSOutputStream *) ftpStream;

        if (self.usernameText.text.length != 0) {
            #pragma unused (success) //Adding this to appease the static analyzer.
            success = [self.networkStream setProperty:self.usernameText.text forKey:(id)kCFStreamPropertyFTPUserName];
            assert(success);
            success = [self.networkStream setProperty:self.passwordText.text forKey:(id)kCFStreamPropertyFTPPassword];
            assert(success);
        }

        self.networkStream.delegate = self;
        [self.networkStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [self.networkStream open];

        // Have to release ftpStream to balance out the create.  self.networkStream 
        // has retained this for our persistent use.

        CFRelease(ftpStream);

        // Tell the UI we're sending.

        [self _sendDidStart];
    }
}
```

Those action perform the upload,but just for images which are inside my project folder.So how can upload an image that i've selected from my camera roll?

NOTICE:I've already create an UIImageView and made it display an image from camera roll,as normal,but how can upload those image which is displayed in the UIImageView

Comment: what about encoding the image to base64, that will give an NSString, post the string to server and process the string via web script to produce an image? then save the image to your server

Comment: Can you provide some sample code or tutorial,i've searched here but i didn't find nothing!Sorry i forgot to mention that i'm a beginner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

download these [library](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html) .

how to use it:

```
#import "NSData+Base64.h"
@implementation.....
-(void)encodeImageAndSendToServer
{
//prepare the image
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImageView.image, 1.0);
myImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];    
NSString *myImageAsString = [imageData base64EncodedString];
}
@end
```

you can now post myImageAsString to server.. process the myImageAsString data in your web script. if you want to use php,[this](http://pastebin.com/thEn2cyq) might help you..

This is how i manage the image in my web server.

```
            <?php
            $imagestring = "your posted NSString from iphone";
            $file_name = 'myImage.jpg';
            $img = imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode($imagestring));
           if($img != false)
            {
             imagejpeg($img, '../images/comprofiler/gallery/'.$file_name);
            }
```

Comment: So,i've already download and imported the library,now i need to create an HTTP Request and send my NSString with this data to a PHP file in my server,and after the image will be uploaded to my directory?

Comment: Sorry but its no clear to me,i tried to put it to work the simulator just crashed with no errors!

Comment: I've created an action and pasted your code but simulator keeps crashing when i click in the button!How i link the NSString to the PHP?

Comment: to make everything easy. I suggest, use this libray https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request to post you NSString to server

Comment: tutorial for adding the ASIHTTPRequest lib can be found here
http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

when you are done. use the ASIFormDataRequest class, or better yet. post another question so we can paste some code for you

Comment: Thanks for help and time,finally i've build it with success.The main problem was on the server,that wasn't allowing me to upload the images,now everything is working properly!Thanks.

Comment: Now in 2013, this code is outdated and no longer works. Imports dont work either. No such file

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't access image file in your albums directly you have to use Assets Library to grab NSData of the image file and upload that binary buffer directly  (create your fileStream as [NSInputStream inputStreamWithData: ...]

How to get NSData of the asset
[iOS: Select a GIF from the photo library, convert to NSData for use in multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187251/ios-select-a-gif-from-the-photo-library-convert-to-nsdata-for-use-in-multipart)

The other method mentioned in this thread involves actually recompressing image data with potential loss of quality/fidelity which might be crucial in certain situations.