# save sign up view controller text values on the server through php web service call using post method in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios

i have sign up form in which i have the fields like first name,last name,gender,email,password,user image,age. i want to make save this user information on the server through php webservice call.how can i pass these parameters to service url? will i use the http request using post method to save the user info to server and when that user wants to log in iOS app , i may match the credencial for that user. in shore, i need a log in and sign up screen for my iOS app, please suggest me any tutorial

Thanks in advance to all of you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need nto create php script and then transfer data through NSURL.

```
NSURL * url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.0.6/savedevicedata.php?Udid=%@&Flag=%d&DateTime=%@",uniqueIdentifier,Flag,FinalDate]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSLog(@"%@",request);
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    //[request setHTTPBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",rawStr]];       

    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *err;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
    NSLog(@"responseData: %@", responseData);
```

Try this Code just replaces the your field.

Comment: it works for my iOS app above both answere but not for the image,how can i upload the image.jpg file to the server.i want to save the image file on the server at http://www.grafixtreme.com/webserver/uploads/users/282013084409.jpg and i m showing the image from the photo library of iPhone,please how can i send the image name to server like fName mentioned above and how to save the image file on the server mentioned above address,thanks a lot in advance, and how can i mark the correct answere for both of above

Comment: if my answer help a little bit upvote that means other user know this way is also correct..

Comment: and if you want to work with image then you need to save that image into bundle only pass the name of that image to json...

Comment: thanks a lot, but would u plz make me understand from the code example, u know  my app scenario like above mentioned, and explain plz  how can i make the login view login, two fields are there , eamil and password, have to compare with the values which i saved in the sign up like NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"fname=%@&lname=%@&eamil=%@&password=%@&age=%@&gender=%@",txtFName.text,txtLName.text,txtEmail.text,txtPassword.text,txtAge.text,txtGender.text];NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];        continue

Comment: if i get the image from the iPhone library and show it on the image view, the next step is how to save that image on server like my other fields mentioned above txtFName,txtLName etc, is it right to divide it into two parts for ease of newcomers First to send the name of the image to server and Second to upload or save image on server if i am not wrong, plz plz give me the code example or any tutorial which can help me out , thanks in advance for all

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647756/how-can-i-upload-an-image-to-server-directory-directly-form-ios-using-ftp       See that link you will get an idea.... if my answer is helpful to you upvote it....