# Getting NSData from an NSURL

Tags: alassetslibrary

I am trying to upload a photo from my app into a web service.

The flow I am attempting to create is as follows:

> 1. User takes photo with camera
> 2. Photo is saved to camera roll under a custom album
> 3. URL of the saved photo is given to my store
> 4. Store attempts to upload the photo to a web service.

I am trying to use `NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[item assetURL]]` where item is a model that contains the URL concerned. But this line is not producing a data when I log it even if it produces a URL: `"assets-library://asset/asset.PNG?id=28DBC0AC-21FF-4560-A9D6-5F4BCA190BDB&ext=PNG"`

The code snippets are as follows:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];



    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(void){

        [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:image.CGImage orientation:image.imageOrientation completionBlock:^(NSURL* assetURL, NSError* error) {

            BCard *card = [[BCard alloc]init];

            //error handling
            if (error!=nil) {
                NSLog(@"[ERROR] - %@",error);
                return;
            }

            //add the asset to the custom photo album
            [library addAssetURL: assetURL
                         toAlbum:@"Business Cards"
             withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                 if (error!=nil) {
                     NSLog(@"Custom Album Error: %@", [error description]);
                 }
             }];

            [card setAssetURL:assetURL];

            [[BCardStore sharedStore]addToQueue:card];
            int index = [[[BCardStore sharedStore]getQueue]count]-1;

            [[BCardStore sharedStore]uploadItemAtIndex:index withProgressBlock:nil withExitBlock:nil];

        }];
    }];


}
```

and

```
-(void)uploadItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index withProgressBlock:(progressBlock)pBlock withExitBlock:(exitBlock)eBlock
{
    BCard *item = [uploadQueue objectAtIndex:index];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.0.116:8080"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[item assetURL]];
    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc]initWithBaseURL:url];
    numberedName = numberedName +1;
    NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",numberedName];

    NSLog(@"%@",[item assetURL]);

//upload data using AFNetworking here
}
```

The snippet `[library addAssetUrl:NSUrl toAlbum:NSString withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error)]` came from the category I found [here](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/ios5-saving-photos-in-custom-photo-album-category-for-download/).

Am I really getting the right URL here or am I using `dataWithContentsOfURL` incorrectly?

Comment: so I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187251/ios-select-a-gif-from-the-photo-library-convert-to-nsdata-for-use-in-multipart) while poking around. It seems too much code to add and I'm pretty concerned with memory as I would have an NSData and bytea object present while I'm uploading the photo. Could there be a more direct approach?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way is You can retrieve the UIImage from Photo-Library using ALAsset URL and convert in to NSData.

**Add ALAssetLibrary**

**Import ALAssetLibrary header file**

```
-(void)uploadItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index 
       withProgressBlock:(progressBlock)pBlock 
           withExitBlock:(exitBlock)eBlock
{  

    ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset)
    {
        ALAssetRepresentation *rep;
        if([myasset defaultRepresentation] == nil) {
            return;
        } else {
            rep = [myasset defaultRepresentation];
        }
        CGImageRef iref = [rep fullResolutionImage];

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{


            UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref];            
            NSData *data = //convert the myImage to NSData

            BCard *item = [uploadQueue objectAtIndex:index];
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.0.116:8080"];  
            AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc]initWithBaseURL:url];
            numberedName = numberedName +1;
            NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",numberedName];



            //upload data using AFNetworking here


        });//end block


    };
    ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureblock  = ^(NSError *myerror)
    {
        NSLog(@"Cant get image - %@",[myerror localizedDescription]);
    };

    NSURL *asseturl = 
        [NSURL URLWithString:[self.photoPath objectAtIndex:[arrayIndex intValue] ]];
    //using ARC , you have to declare ALAssetsLibrary as member variable 
    ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init]; 

    [assetslibrary assetForURL:assetURL 
                   resultBlock:resultblock
                  failureBlock:failureblock]; 

}
```