# Objective-C/CocoaHTTPServer - Return an image how response

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoahttpserver

I have this simple method that check if i pass a parameter like "/testPhoto", and if, it is passed, i want try to answer with a simple image that has the path that you can see in the variable "testPath" (static path for try). At the moment, when i do the request, i receive the 200 ok status from the server, but no data is passed (0 Bytes). I need to understand what i'm doing wrong. Maybe the testPath doesn't contains a correct path? The path that i'm using is found using the ALAssetslibrary.

```
- (NSObject<HTTPResponse> *)httpResponseForMethod:(NSString *)method URI:(NSString *)path{

  HTTPLogTrace();

  if ([path isEqualToString:@"/testPhoto"]){
    NSString *testPath = [[NSString alloc] init];
    testPath = @"assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=DB96E240-8760-4FD6-B8B4-FEF3F61793B3&ext=JPG";
    NSURL *deviceImageUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:testPath];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:deviceImageUrl];
    UIImage *deviceImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

    HTTPDataResponse *photoResponse = [[HTTPDataResponse alloc] initWithData:imageData];
    return photoResponse;
  }

return nil;

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you access the assets-library URL. This is not a standard URL and loading the data from an assets-library URL does not work like this. Here is an example how to do it: [Getting NSData from an NSURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13301404/getting-nsdata-from-an-nsurl/13523463#13523463)

The following code is based on the above example. I'm not an expert in `ALAssetLibrary`, so try it with care. It needs quite some code to make the asynchronous working of the asset library synchronous again:

```
- (NSObject<HTTPResponse> *)httpResponseForMethod:(NSString *)method URI:(NSString *)path{

    HTTPLogTrace();

    if ([path isEqualToString:@"/testPhoto"]){
        NSData* __block data = nil;

        dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
        dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_main_queue();

        ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset)
        {
            ALAssetRepresentation *rep;
            if([myasset defaultRepresentation] == nil) {
                return;
            } else {
                rep = [myasset defaultRepresentation];
            }
            CGImageRef iref = [rep fullResolutionImage];

            dispatch_sync(queue, ^{
                UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref];
                *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImage, 1);
            });

            dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
        };
        ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureblock  = ^(NSError *myerror)
        {
            NSLog(@"Cant get image - %@",[myerror localizedDescription]);

            dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
        };

        NSString *testPath = @"assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=DB96E240-8760-4FD6-B8B4-FEF3F61793B3&ext=JPG";
        NSURL *deviceImageUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:testPath];
        ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init]; //usin ARC , you have to declare ALAssetsLibrary as member variable
        [assetslibrary assetForURL:deviceImageUrl
                       resultBlock:resultblock
                      failureBlock:failureblock];

        dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

        dispatch_release(sema);


        HTTPDataResponse *photoResponse = [[HTTPDataResponse alloc] initWithData:imageData];
        return photoResponse;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have modify the code how you suggest. Actually the log return to an imageData.length equal to 0. Do you think that the path that i'm passing is wrong?

Comment: thank you very much for your help. I have tried your code and there are only two errors. I fixed them and now it works perfectly! Thank you very much man!