# IOS: Get NSData from Photos path

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I have an array of image paths from the Photos gallery. I need to publish those photos via my Facebook app. But I'm getting error 324, "requires upload file". I think the way I'm getting NSData from the path is wrong. Any help?

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: URLImages[i]]];
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               messageTextView.text, @"message", imageData, @"source", nil];
```

But When i hard code the image inside the project, it working

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"IMAG0386" ofType:@"jpg"];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    mosaicShareImages[i]]];
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               messageTextView.text, @"message", imageData, @"source", nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to access the Assets Library URLs (Starts with `assets-library://`) the `NSData` method `dataWithContentsOfURL:` will fail and return `nil`. This method does not have the required permissions to access the image related to the asset URL. To read from assets library you need to use `ALAssetsLibrary`'s

```
- (void)assetForURL:(NSURL *)assetURL 
        resultBlock:(ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock)resultBlock 
        failureBlock:(ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock)failureBlock
```

method. As you can see the API takes blocks for failure and success as arguments. This method is asynchronous because the user may need to be asked to grant access to the data.

More about API [from Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/ALAssetsLibrary/assetForURL:resultBlock:failureBlock:)

> When the asset is requested, the user may be asked to confirm the application's access to the library; the method, though, returns immediately. You should perform whatever work you want with the asset in resultBlock.
>   If the user denies access to the application, or if no application is allowed to access the data, the failure block is called.

How to use this API can be found in this answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/13523463/1407017

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",URLImages]];

NSLog(@"%@",url);

NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];

UIImage * img=[UIImage imageWithData:data];

ImgView.image=img;
```

try this one..

Comment: Same error, and url print like.

assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=F30FFA87-C329-4C21-AA00-0FF3A985A2A1&ext=JPG

Answer (score 0):

Try this changes in code :

`NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",URLImages[i]]]]`;

Answer (score 0):

If your array URLImages[i] contains the absolute path of the image file, then you need to use `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:]` like below:

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath: URLImages[i]]];
```