# how to show ios photo library gif on uiimageview

Tags: ios, uiimageview, gif, alasset, alassetlibrary

i have implemented image picker controller delegate:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
NSString *mediaType = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
if ([mediaType isEqualToString:@"public.image"]) {
    UIImage *anImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
//i know i can get image name from info key.
    if(self.block) self.block(YES, anImage, nil);
}
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

i am using UIImageView+PlayGIF category to show gif images (loader in my app) from **main resource bundle** successfully.Some thing like:

```
NSData *gifData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"loading_image.gif" ofType:nil]];
CGRect bnd = view.bounds;
loader.gifView = [[YFGIFImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(bnd.size.width/2-60, bnd.size.height/2-70, 120, 120)];
loader.gifView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
loader.gifView.gifData = gifData;
```

Questions:
So how can i export photo library gif to document directory as (whatevername.gif), and use above category to show gif.

Or can i get direct nsdata from photolibrary and use above category to show gif.(**i prefer this**).

I have not tried with UIWebView, can i show gif on UIWebView.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

set property of imageView.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *YFGIFImageView;
```

Download the Class of GIF imageLoad with `UIImageView`

[GIFImageLoad](http://ge.tt/2Nju1TK2/v/0)

Now load Data from `NSBundle`.

```
    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"loading_image" withExtension:@"gif"];
```

Load image with `animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFData` as below.

```
    self.YFGIFImageView.image = [UIImage animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
```

**OR**

Load image with URL `animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFURL` as below.

```
    self.YFGIFImageView.image = [UIImage animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFURL:url];
```

**OR**

Load image with GIFURL `animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFURL` as below.

```
    self.YFGIFImageView.image = [UIImage animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFURL:url];
```

Comment: thank you very much for your response (already doing it), but i want to use pho library (ALAsset) to get gifData, and use YGF Category to show data.Please read my question again

Comment: Hmm, I understand fetching GIF from library

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187251/ios-select-a-gif-from-the-photo-library-convert-to-nsdata-for-use-in-multipart

Comment: Try above to get GIF image from library,

Comment: ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [asset defaultRepresentation];
 NSLog(@"%@",[representation url]);